# How do I sort values by name that have a matching element?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting

In this DataFrame, the teams need to stay in the same position, but I want to sort the players within each team.

```
                 Team                Player  Apps
0    Newcastle_United             Joelinton   5.0
1    Newcastle_United   Allan Saint-Maximin   5.0
2    Newcastle_United         Callum Wilson   5.0
3    Newcastle_United      Jamaal Lascelles   5.0
4    Newcastle_United         Jeff Hendrick   2.0
..                ...                   ...   ...
471           Arsenal            Pablo Marí   2.0
472           Arsenal  Albert Sambi Lokonga   5.0
473           Arsenal       Folarin Balogun   2.0
474           Arsenal          Nuno Tavares   5.0
475           Arsenal                 Total   NaN
```

In this case, the output should look like:

```
                 Team                 Player  Apps
0    Newcastle_United    Allan Saint-Maximin  5.0
1    Newcastle_United          Callum Wilson  5.0
etc
```

I can't sort by 'Team', 'Player', though, because that would rearrange the order of the teams.

I feel like this should have a pretty simple solution, but I'm stumped.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more convenient way is to use [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) to create an ordered key for `Team` column:

```
>>> df.assign(teamgroup=pd.factorize(df['Team'])[0]) \
      .sort_values(['teamgroup', 'Player']).drop(columns='teamgroup')

                 Team                Player  Apps
1    Newcastle_United   Allan Saint-Maximin   5.0
2    Newcastle_United         Callum Wilson   5.0
3    Newcastle_United      Jamaal Lascelles   5.0
4    Newcastle_United         Jeff Hendrick   2.0
0    Newcastle_United             Joelinton   5.0
472           Arsenal  Albert Sambi Lokonga   5.0
473           Arsenal       Folarin Balogun   2.0
474           Arsenal          Nuno Tavares   5.0
471           Arsenal            Pablo Marí   2.0
475           Arsenal                 Total   NaN
```

Output of `pd.factorize`:

```
>>> pd.factorize(df['Team'])
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 Index(['Newcastle_United', 'Arsenal'], dtype='object'))
```

---

**Old answer**

You can use `sort=False` as argument of `groupby` and sort inside the group.

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby('Team', sort=False)['Player'] \
             .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values()) \
             .index.get_level_values(1)]

                 Team                Player  Apps
1    Newcastle_United   Allan Saint-Maximin   5.0
2    Newcastle_United         Callum Wilson   5.0
3    Newcastle_United      Jamaal Lascelles   5.0
4    Newcastle_United         Jeff Hendrick   2.0
0    Newcastle_United             Joelinton   5.0
472           Arsenal  Albert Sambi Lokonga   5.0
473           Arsenal       Folarin Balogun   2.0
474           Arsenal          Nuno Tavares   5.0
471           Arsenal            Pablo Marí   2.0
475           Arsenal                 Total   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort by **multiple** **columns** in a **Pandas Table**

```
df.sort_values(by=['Team', 'Player'])
```

**Sample Script Demo Sort by **multiple** **columns** in a **Pandas Table****

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'np.nan', 'D', 'C'],
    'col2': [2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 4],
    'col3': [0, 1, 9, 4, 2, 3],
    'col4': ['a', 'B', 'c', 'D', 'e', 'F']
})

print("Print Data Frame")
print(df)

print("Print Sort By Column 1")
a = df.sort_values(by=['col1'])
print(a)

print("Print Sort By Column 1, Column 2")
b = df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2'])
print(b)
```

[image]